# Change paragraph spacing without messing up the rest of the document

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, parskip

If I use

```
\setlength{\parskip}{1cm plus4mm minus3mm}
```

Or change the lengh of parskip in anyway, it not only changes the space between paragraphs, but also the space before and after equations, the contents page, figures, titles, sections, subsections and everything else.

How can I just add a vertical space between paragraphs of text?

The only way I can do it at the moment is to use 4 slashes after each paragraph and then \indent at the start of each paragraph like this:

```
This is the first paragraph.
\\\\
\indent This is the second paragraph.
```

This makes the source look messy (and is also a bit too big of a gap). Is there a way to automatically insert a space after a paragraph of text, but not change anything else?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the [`parskip`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package or switch to one of the KOMA classes with some of the various `parskip=` options. Also, if you increase the distance between paragraphs, indentation of first lines is redundant.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Oh okay, I didn't realize that, I've never been any good at grammar/formatting. In your personal opinion, what looks better, having a space between paragraphs or an indent? With the indent it looked cramped to me, but this is the default style so it would be much easier to do it like this.

Comment: @Blue7 I'd say (and this is a personal opinion as a mathematician, since I am not typographer not editor) that for a scientifica publication, the preferred way is to use indentation instead of increased separation between paragraphs; for other kind of works, the invreased separation between paragraphs (with no indentation) can be used if it's consistent with the general layout of the work.

Comment: It's also the preferred way for literary books. In my opinion, adding a vertical space between paragraphs should be used to insist on two paragraphs having a really distinct content. If you find the default style too cramped, you can slighly increase the interline spacing with the `\setspace` package: writing `setstretch{1.06}` could be a good choice.

Comment: if you really want extra space between two paragraphs, type a blank line, `\bigskip`, and another blank line, then start your next paragraph.  or you can define `\myskip` to be `\vspace{<dimen>}` to the distance you want.  don't use `\vspace*` since that will insert the space even if it happens to occur at the beginning of a page, and you really don't want that.

Comment: either way just never use `\\ ` to fake a paragraph it does not make a paragraph and the faking it by adding an explicit `\indent` doesn't really fill in the gaps. You should hardly ever use `\\ ` except for its use in alignments.

Comment: Indentation is also preferred in humanities papers. However, I sometimes use no indentation and increased skip for things like handouts or in letters.